# How to make one item take 2 columns masonry bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found way to use massonary just with html & css, but problem is I cannot find way to put one item in 2 columns....

Here is example:

http://www.bootply.com/118335

Any solution for this?

Comment: Please clarify. You want 2 columns across instead of 4?

Comment: No, I want some items to take 2 columns instead 1.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with CSS multi columns.

Comment: Maybe http://masonry.desandro.com is what you're looking for

Comment: I can't use that lib...

Comment: try to use flex maybe